# Javascript animation is not running

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an animated menu that slides up and down. Unfortunately it's not working. I've checked the error console and there are no syntax errors. Here's my Javascript:

```
function showLayer() {
    var hiddenLayer = document.getElementById("mainmenu");
    var layerPosition = parseInt(hiddenLayer.style.bottom);
    if (layerPosition > 700) {
        hiddenLayer.style.bottom = (layerPosition + 5) + "px";
        setTimeout("showLayer()", 20);
    }
}

function hideLayer() {
    var hiddenLayer = document.getElementByID("mainmenu");
    hiddenLayer.style.bottom = "700px";
}
```

Here's the whole context:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showLayer() {
var hiddenLayer = document.getElementById("mainmenu");
var layerPosition = parseInt(hiddenLayer.style.bottom);
if (layerPosition > 700) {
hiddenLayer.style.bottom = (layerPosition + 5) + "px";
setTimeout("showLayer()", 20);
}
}
function hideLayer() {
var hiddenLayer = document.getElementByID("mainmenu");
hiddenLayer.style.bottom = "700px";
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
div#mainmenu { position: absolute; bottom: 700px; left: 9px; width: 600px; 
height: 350px; border-style: solid; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) ; border-    
width: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 7px; border-top-left-radius: 7px; }
div#mainbutton { position: absolute; top: 674px; left: 12px; width: 28px;     
height: 28px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-width: 
1px; border-radius: 4px; }
div#mainbuttontext { position: absolute; top: 679px; left: 22px; color: rgb(255, 255, 
255); font-style: normal; font-size: 18px; font-family:"Arial"; }
</style>

<div id="mainbutton"></div>
<div id="mainmenu" onClick="showLayer('mainmenu')">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="mainbuttontext">F</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried `var layerPosition = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(hiddenLayer , null).bottom,10);`?

Comment: No I haven't. I'll try that right now.

Comment: Firstly, can you give us your css? Secondly, you wrote `getElementByID("mainmenu")` in the function `hideLayer` instead of `getElementById("mainmenu")`. Look at the d of id. Thirdly, try to write `onclick` instead of `onClick` (I am not sure, but it may affect).

Comment: Consider using http://jsbeautifier.org on your JS to make it more readable. =]

Comment: It looks like I have a positioning problem. I'll get back to you when I get things fixed.

Comment: Mageek, unfortunately it hasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your problem! It's something very strange and I can't explain it, but to **get** style in javascript, the css must be inline (to **set** a style it's not necessary).

So I modified your code by placing the css inline.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="mainmenu" style="position:absolute;bottom:100px;" onclick="showLayer('mainmenu');">Click me!</div>

<!--I wrote 100px just for the test, you can change it and modify the js-->
```

**JS :**

```
function showLayer()
{
    var hiddenLayer=document.getElementById("mainmenu");
    var layerPosition=parseInt(hiddenLayer.style.bottom);
    if(layerPosition>50)
    {
        hiddenLayer.style.bottom=(layerPosition+5)+"px";
        setTimeout("showLayer()",20);
    }
}

function hideLayer()
{
    var hiddenLayer=document.getElementById("mainmenu");
    hiddenLayer.style.bottom="700px";
}
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/8MWfV/

And here is a fiddle that shows that a not inline css doesn't works : http://jsfiddle.net/kfUrP/