# Getting the element position - { absolute|relative|fixed } returning null value?

Tags: javascript, position

Using javascript - we can set the element relative position such as

`object.style.position="absolute"||"fixed"||"relative"`

But,on using the same `console.log(object.style.position)` - it does not return the position applied on the object - it returns `NULL`. Am i missing something here or is there another way to achieve what i'm trying to achieve??

Comment: It's working : http://jsfiddle.net/9TpfT/

Comment: @mageek - not working(what i actually want) version - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TpfT/1/)

Comment: It'll return null only if it hasn't been explicitly set.  If it has been set then it will return the value.

Comment: Yes, because I don't know why, but you can't `get` the style of an object if this css isn't inline (but you can `set` it). See my other answer here : http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10919859/javascript-animation-is-not-runing/10920445

Comment: @uncle that's the problem - how to retrieve it(if it was specified in CSS) was my question.. :)

Comment: Ok, so pimvdb's solution might be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.style` represents what's set on the element itself, much like the `style` attribute.

You could instead use `getComputedStyle`: http://jsfiddle.net/qAbTz/1/.

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");

console.log(div.style.position);              // "" (not null by the way)
console.log(getComputedStyle(div).position);​  // "fixed"
```

Comment: Browser compatibility?.. [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle#Browser_compatibility)  .. but,quirks has provided a work around.. so,will look into it.. thanks.. :)

Comment: @Vivek Chandra: jQuery supports it on other browsers as well I believe; you could look at its source to see how. Seems like it uses `.currentStyle` if available.

Comment: Currently not using jQuery as of now. Want to solve it myself - looking into this solution by [quirks](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html).. hoping it would solve my problem

Comment: @Vivek Chandra: I wasn't recommending using jQuery :) It seems that article is also talking about `.currentStyle`.

Comment: Yes.. nice workaround they've recommended.. so,will look it up.. thanks for the `getComputedStyle` - put me in the right direction..

Comment: Damn. That function is slow though, is there not another alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Note also (by the same logic presented by pimvdb), if you specify an initial position as part of the object's style, it is accessible by div.style.position.

```
<div id="div" style="position: absolute;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qAbTz/4/